# Setting joint angle from a slider makes joint spin continuously

Tags: unity, c#, rotation

I use sliders to change the rotation angle of my joint, like this:

```
a = sliderx.GetComponent<Xslider>().sl.value;
b = slidery.GetComponent<Yslider>().sl.value;
headjoint.transform.Rotate(a, b, 0);
```

After I slide the bar, the joint continues rotating around and won't stop.

It's like it's doing

```
a += value
```

and not

```
a = value
```

Shouldn't the slider give me a single definite number?

Why?  Do I need to use Euler angles?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a crosspost from StackOverflow. Crossposting on stack exchange sites is not allowed. Select the site where you think you'll get the best/most answers and ask only there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the wrong method for what you want to do.

[As you can see explained in the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html), `Transform.Rotate` applies an *incremental* rotation to an object, *on top* of whatever rotation it already had.

It explicitly promises to do a `a += value`

So if you want `a = value` then *don't use this function*, because it does not do that!

You want something like this instead:

```
headjoint.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(a, b, 0);
```

or

```
headjoint.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(a, b, 0);
```

Notice that these both express `a = value` instead of `a += value`.